# How do I mock SQLiteDatabase instance?

Tags: android, mockito, android-testing

In my class to be tested, I have this code in the constructor

```
public MyClass (Context context){
    String db = context.getDatabasePath("mydb.db").getPath();
    this.connection = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(db, null);
}
```

mydb.db is located in src/test/resources

This is  my test class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest   {
    MyClass myClass;
    @Mock
    Context context;
    @Mock
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        URL resource =this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("mydb.db");
        File file = new File(resource.getPath());
        doReturn(file).when(context).getDatabasePath("mydb.db");
        myClass=new MyClass(context);    
    }
}
```

When running test, i've got the exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method openOrCreateDatabase in android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
```

I've added this in my build.gradle

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
```

Now the exception got rid off.

but the connection of MyClass is null !

Is it possible to test this only using Mockito?

Comment: I've already use resources for other tests, and it works